# MaterialApp init function/widget with proper context

Tags: flutter, dart

Like every other app that I created I have some boilerplate code that I need to execute before loading the application:

- session check
- store hydration
- route change listener
- user session listener
- ...

This code, more often than not, requires a `BuildContext` context to be available. I cannot use the context that sits at the same level with `MaterialApp` due to complaints from flutter so I need to go deeper 1+ levels in order to grab a context from a descendant. That descendant is my home route and it obviously fails when you navigate away.

What is a proper place to grab a context and initiate my watchers app wide? Where would you continuously watch for a navigation change for example?

Comment: I believe you can use routeObserver property of MaterialApp to pass routeObserver from your routeChangeListener.

Comment: It was just an example. I have many other bits that need to be running.

Comment: I don't think except for something which is widget tree related, you will need context. Anyways, navigation would be only thing which will depend on MaterialApp, for rest of the part, you can wrap everything in Builder which will give you a context.

Comment: Even getting a cubit out of bloc (to access state) requires context: `BlocProvider.of<ProfileCubit>(context);` You mean the `builder` part of `MAterialApp`?

Comment: No, Builder is a widget as well. If everything is at top, you don't need BlocProvider to create bloc object. You can directly create one yourself and use it. BlocProvider is used to traverse in widget tree to find nearestAncestor of Bloc-Type.

Comment: I'm obviously too early in my flutter days. Can you answer with a small example so I can vote it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235288/discussion-between-user6327816-and-romeo-mihalcea).